# sql performance degrading - loading 60,000 xml files - ssis - xml source

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, performance, ssis

I have a ssis data flow task which loads xml data into sql database - more than 60,000  xml files. My first few thousands of xml files gets loaded into the table faster. But as time progresses, the loading speed is reduced drastically. 
first 10k files gets loaded in 10 minutes approx. next 10k takes 25 minutes, then slowly the performance degrades. By the time all my 60k+ files get loaded, it takes around 4 hours.

Is there any way to keep a check on the performance and load the files with the same speed as that for the initial files.

I have tried with bulk copy in c# too. But the issue exist even there as well. Is their any work around method to improve my performance ?

Comment: Can you reach the XML files from your SQL Server directly? Might be easier (and much faster) to load them with pure T-SQL...

Answer (score 0):

Parts of your code would make it easier for us to give you tips and ideas!

I believe that this issue is memory related. Are you reading all of the files into the memory before putting it in the sql database? 
Check the Task Manager! If the memory usage keeps growing and growing, you have a potential issue with the memory usage.

I don't know how the files are stored or named, but if you could - why not work with like 1-5000 at a time, move them and take the next?

Comment: I have a ForEach container which pulls all the files and then load file by file into my destination table. Foreach has a data flow task in which there is XML source and oledb destination.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with multiple DFT's instead of a single DFT. Limiting each one to around 5k/10k. This would result in lesser time frame hopefully.

Also, the difference in time might be due to the indexing on the table. Remove the indexing. Load the records. Reapply indexing once the loading is done. To query record sets on an indexed table is fast. But performing Insert on an indexed table and that too 60k records is a time consuming process.

Answer (score 0):

1.execute SQL Task (Drop index Before Loading)

2.for loop ( Multiple Control flow for xml file load)

3.execute SQL Task (Recreate Index)